# Firestore array-contains-any not working with array value?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am having firestore collection but filter query not working as expected but it's abominably its work when i filter from firebase Database UI.

Code:

```
const docBookingRef = firestore().collection("booking").where("parentCase", "array-contains-any", [66])
docBookingRef.get().then((doc) => {
    const list = [];
    doc.forEach(function (docV) {
      list.push(docV.data());
    });
    console.log('booking list', list);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('booking error', error);

  })
```

Comment: Honestly, your query appears to be correct, have you tried something like `.where("parentCase", "array-contains", 66)` just in case to check if you get that document?

Comment: @ralemos The syntax looks correct if you compare to what's seen in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any

Comment: Your code is not checking for errors on the promise returned by `get()`.  There could be an error and you might not know it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Code has been updated. but its not going in catch function. Shows me a empty list

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to recreate the problem in this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/bisadet/1/edit?js,console). My collection has a single document with an array field `parentCase` and a single value `66` in there.

Aside from that, but code is a pretty direct copy of yours:

```
const query = root.where("parentCase", "array-contains-any", [66])
query.get().then((doc) => {
  const list = [];
  doc.forEach(function (docV) {
    list.push(docV.data());
  });
  console.log('booking list', list);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log('booking error', error);
})
```

Are you sure your array contains a numeric value, and not a string `"66"`? For the latter case, the query would have to be: `where("parentCase", "array-contains-any", ["66"])`.